# Which were the 4 social classes mentioned in Rurouni Kenshin Meiji Kenkaku Romantan episode 5?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin, japan

In *Rurouni Kenshin: Meiji Kenkaku Romantan* episode 5, they mention people fought to end the 4 social classes that existed in Japan, so all people would be equal. This is apparently a re-make of the 90's series; also there was a manga, OVAs, an animated movie, live action movies, etc. so I suppose anywhere it was mentioned. Also this might be what historically happened in Japan or not, since certain ideas are historically accurate, and others aren't or are loosely  based. I suppose 2 of the social classes were farmer and samurai, but not sure which would be the others.

Which were the 4 social classes mentioned in Rurouni Kenshin Meiji Kenkaku Romantan episode 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four classes in feudal Japan were:

1. samurai
2. farmers
3. artisans
4. merchants

These were legal classifications; the emperor and his court were above them, and the *burakumin*, including professions such as actor or butcher, were below it.